# Where can I find the vote distribution of an EU directive?

Tags: european-union, european-parliament

Recently the EU Parliament voted on the [“Copyright Directive”](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52016PC0593).

I would like to know exactly which parties/individuals voted for and against this directive.

I have been looking for this information for over an hour online using various keywords but I have failed to locate such a list.

Is there a URL depicting this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is [the relevant page on the website of the European Parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/votes.html?tab=votes). All votes are listed here. If the voting process is not anonymous, individual votes are recorded in the documents.

[This is the link to all non-anonymous votes from Wednesday](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-%2f%2fEP%2f%2fNONSGML%2bPV%2b20180912%2bRES-RCV%2bDOC%2bPDF%2bV0%2f%2fEN&language=EN). The Copyright Directive had the following number: A8-0245/2018.

Comment: Note that there first were lots of votes about proposed changes to the text. The final vote is on pages 38 to 39.

Comment: @chirlu Thank you for the note about pages 38-39. This document is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

VoteWatch is a source I personally regularly use as they display all votes in a very user-friendly format. You can sort MEP's based on Member State and political group.

**Here is the final vote for the Copyright Directive:**
https://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-copyright-in-the-digital-single-market-draft-legislative-resolution-vote-commission-proposal-ordinar.html

("registration" is required but they only ask for email and don't verify it)

I do not work not have any affiliation with VoteWatch, I purely use them for easy acccessability.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is indeed very user friendly and exactly what I was looking for. Registration is annoying but other than that fantastic.